# Facebook Login Limit

Tags: facebook

I'm building a page using Facebook Connect, and the interaction in relation to Login/Logout is quite complex. Thus, I have to test it quite a bit. However, Facebook likes to prevent my login after a particular number of attempts, especially if I've mistyped my password at any point.

Does anybody out there know if there's a way to increase this limit or activate a "sandbox" mode which would remove this limit for developers of my application?

My research seems to suggest that I won't be happy with the answer, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent found any sandbox-mode, but have testet extensively against 'live' facebook and have never been preventet login... you can however make up some testusers on facebook, but I don't know if this will suit your testing needs.

Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ for more in depth on facebook test users.